# Не работает callback_query_handler()

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types


class RqBot(telebot.TeleBot):
    def __init__(self, token: str):
        super().__init__(token)
        self.register_message_handler(self.gg, commands=['gg'])
        self.register_callback_query_handler(self.query_handler, lambda call: True)

    def gg(self, msg: types.Message):
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('a', callback_data='123'))
        self.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'jj', reply_markup=markup)

    def query_handler(self, data: types.CallbackQuery):
        print(data.message.text + '<')


def run_service(token: str):
    bot = RqBot(token)
    bot.polling(skip_pending=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_service("MyToken")
```

Проблема в следующем: Обработчик query_handler не отвечает на нажатие InlineKeyboardButton

А мне надо, что бы он отвечал на него и данная функция все таки вызывалась.

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Я просто удалил старого бота. И создал нового. Что поменялось? Токен. Остальное осталось без изменений.